# How to get localized time symbols in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Is there a way in iOS to get all time symbols base on current local and 24 hour time format.

i.e

> if 24 hour clock - 00:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00 .... 23:00
>   if 12 hour clock - 12 AM, 1 AM, 2 AM, 3 AM .... 11 PM

The above returned array should be based on current locale.
The AM/PM symbols should be localized.

We have methods to get weekDays Symbols and month symbols which return an array of NSString objects that specify symbols.But I could not find something similar for time symbols
Ex -

```
(NSArray *)shortStandaloneMonthSymbols;
(NSArray *)shortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols;
```

Currently I have hard coded the array as

```
NSString *hoursAMPM[] = {@" 12 AM", @" 1 AM", @" 2 AM", @" 3 AM", @" 4 AM", @" 5 AM", @" 6 AM", @" 7 AM", @" 8 AM", @" 9 AM", @" 10 AM", @" 11 AM",@" 12 PM", @" 1 PM", @" 2 PM", @" 3 PM", @" 4 PM", @" 5 PM", @" 6 PM", @" 7 PM", @" 8 PM", @" 9 PM", @" 10 PM", @" 11 PM"
```

};

```
NSString *hours24Hr[] = {@" 00:00", @" 01:00", @" 02:00", @" 03:00", @" 04:00", @" 05:00", @" 06:00", @" 07:00", @" 08:00", @" 09:00", @" 10:00", @" 11:00",@" 12:00", @" 13:00", @" 14:00", @" 15:00", @" 16:00", @" 17:00", @" 18:00", @" 19:00", @" 20:00", @" 21:00", @" 22:00", @" 23:00"
```

};

It works fine with english locale but the problem is that it does not change with locale change,
**ie** some languages show AM/PM as a.m/p.m 

also 24hr format varies ex.it can be 01:00 or 1:00 depending on locale.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AMSymbol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBIGJFD) and [PMSymbol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBDIHCE) on `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[NSLocale currentLocale]` 
maybe something like this

```
NSString *template = NSLocalizedString(@"HH:mm", nil);
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:template options:0 locale:locale];
```